# Program works only in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I've written a program that does extensive use of EasyHook. The program works just fine if I run it from Visual studio ( either in debug or release mode), but it stops working ( or better, it stops hooking) if I run it from the release folder.
The question is simple, why? I run both visual studio and the application with the same user, on the same machine, so there should be no difference...

Comment: what is the error you get when running the app outside VS?

Comment: Have you tried running the application from the release folder and attaching the visual studio debugger after starting the application?

Comment: I don't get any error, just the log file ( where i put hooked data) is empty.  @dkson : no, i've not done it, but the application doesn't crash, just doesn't work...

Comment: Please provide a sample program that demonstrates this behavior.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couln't replicate the error in a new program ( sources are quite big, and find out what's the problem is an hard task). By the way, I've done more testing, and it appears that the program works in Visual Studio ( both Debug and Release mode), AND running the Debug mode executables outside VS. So, it seems that the only problematic case is the only one i need :) By the way... distributing debug exes is a terrible idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check in your debug folder if you have any files that are not inside release folder (like .dll and so on) if so copy them to release folder! and if working then, then you probably use some external dll's or some references something like that... and you will also have to include them to your setup project!

Comment: did you try to delete all contents of release folder and then build again?

Comment: you still didnt find solution?

Answer (score 1):

> I run both visual studio and the application with the same user, on the same machine, so there should be no difference

I can make a random guess, since you don't provide much detail, and no error messages in your question.

Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 runs elevated (if I recall correctly).
If you have not disabled UAC, then you will need to run your application as an Administrator.

Comment: VS does not run elevated unless you need it to (to us IIS or debug a running service for example).